# Change language of alert in banner of Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, localization, apple-push-notifications

I am facing problem to change the language of alert in banner when push comes. Actually i am working on an app which works in two language. One is English and second is Norwegian. The push I am receiving from my web server end and what the string it has in `alert` key is displayed in banner when push comes and you are outside of the app. But as a requirement we want that if I change the language from setting from English to Norwegian then when push comes its banner's alert string would also change to Norwegian. Will it be possible at my end or i have to change it from server whenever i change language?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two ways to display localized text in a push notification in iOS:

**Localize the message in your server**

In this case, you must send the device language to your server. The code you need to add to your iOS app would be similar to the following:

```
NSString *preferredLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
const char *langStr = [preferredLanguage UTF8String];
[self sendCurrentLanguage:langStr]; // Method that communicates with your server
```

Then you can send the notification message in the appropriate language by using the `alert` key in the notification JSON payload.

**Send a localization string with the notification payload**

You can send the localized string in the payload. The `alert` key accepts a child `loc-key` key that you can use to send a localized string:

```
"alert" : { 
    "loc-key" : "My Localized String",
    ...
}
```

And then, in your `Localizable.strings` file inside the correspondent language identifier, add the following:

```
"My Localized String" = "The localized string in the language you want.";
```

If you need to pass arguments to build the final localized string, you can pass it as a `loc-args` JSON array in the notification payload, too:

```
"alert" : { 
        "loc-key" : "My Localized String",
        "loc-args" : [ "First argument", "Second argument" ],
        ...
    }
```

And, in your `Localizable.strings`:

```
 "My Localized String" = "The localized string with first argument %@, and second argument %@."
```

Or, if you need to change the positions:

```
 "My Localized String" = "The localized string with second argument %2$@, and first argument %1$@.";
```

Comment: but i have dynamic text which include person name too then how it will be manageable?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra See my updated answer. You can pass arguments inside `loc-args` and use format specifiers for positional substitution.

Comment: is it $ or @? and how it will know where to put first argument and where to second. Is from numbers (1 and 2)?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Yes, the position arguments are `%n$@`, where `n` is a number starting with 1. If you don't need to change the relative position of your arguments, you can use the standard `%@`syntax. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok i am trying and let you know

Comment: hey Daniel i want your help Suppose if i have string "A has accepted request of B" in english then what would come in the Localized string-" has accepted request of " and when we would define localize string in file what format it should have "%@ has accepted request of %@" or " has accepted request of "?

Comment: Another option would be to do nothing since the iOS client automatically adds preferred language HTTP header.  So the server could just pull it out of the request to register the push token.

Comment: So this is only for cases where the language is defined in the device and not by the app itself, right? My app is setting its own language inside itself. I guess the system will only look for the proper plist to load considering the system locale, right?