# iOS Push Notifications Localization

Tags: ios, localization, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nslocalizedstring

I would like to know what is the default behaviour of silent push notifications when the app is on foreground. Will it still display an alert view or not?

When localising the alert message :

```
"alert" : {
            "body" : "Start the game Jenna"
            "loc-key" : "start.game",
            "loc-args" : [ "Jenna"]
 }
```

Does the body message takes precedence over the loc-key? What if the loc-key does not exist on the app?

Comment: Silent push notification = Contant-Avilable 1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language of alert in banner of Push Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609923/change-language-of-alert-in-banner-of-push-notification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs imply that it's either/or: you should either set the `body` or the `loc-key` / `loc-args` properties.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html).

They might fall back to `body` if `loc-key` is not found, or they might never even look it up in `Localizable.strings` when `body` is present. Since docs don't define it, I would not count on the behavior one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested setting both `body_loc_key` and `body`

If the client doesn't have `body_loc_key` in it's `Localizable.strings` it will show the `body` text otherwise it will show the localized string of `body_loc_key`

Which is just what I want and probably what you would expect.