# IOS notification showing twice with default and my notification alert

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I'm not an iOS programmer so bear with me. I'm able to get the push notifications but I get two alerts on my screens.

**Issue 1:** 
-One with the `UIAlertView* alertWindow` I am creating below
- Second seems to be the default notification alert window. What am I doing wrong thats creating the second window ?

**Issue 2:** When the device is locked, I can see the notifications on screen but this is the default notification window. I don't see the notification with the details I'm getting in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Also, I would appreciate If someone can explain the `if else` block in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I copied pasted it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString *AMAZON_SERVER = @"xxxxxx";

    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = APPLICATION_ID;
        configuration.clientKey = CLIENT_KEY;
        configuration.server = AMAZON_SERVER;
    }]];

    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    [Fabric with:@[[Digits class]]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]!=TRUE)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    //storedevice Type in standardUserDefaults
    [self setDeviceType];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary * apsData = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSString* alert = [apsData objectForKey:@"alert"];
    ...
    ...

        UIAlertView* alertWindow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: alertHeader
                                                    message: message
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertWindow show];
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    } else {
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: your are registered twice. so the problem occur

Comment: Please check the device state in didrecieve notification if its active then show alert otherwise not. Because in Active state notification banner will not shown.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Can you please point out where am I registered twice ?

Comment: @SagarShirbhate how to check for device state, did you mean `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

Comment: -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;                
    // the application state.

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)        
    {                
        // Nothing to do if applicationState is Inactive, the iOS already displayed an alert view.                
        [alertView show];          
    }    
}

Comment: check my answer @user1324887

Comment: @SagarShirbhate, when the app state is inactive, I want to show my notification, not the default notification. I need to modify the information shown

Comment: are you uninstall and run it ?

Comment: @user1324887 Please Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609923/change-language-of-alert-in-banner-of-push-notification

Comment: @SagarShirbhate,Figured it out `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` is the problem. after implementing what SagarShirbhate suggested, I was still getting 2 notifications, its obvious.  I had registred twice and also I was firing the notification twice. Thanks a lot

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Thanks, after implementing your suggestion and removing `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` it works.

Comment: if the suggestion is ok for you kindly accept my answer

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P I did, However It doesnt resolve `Issue 2`,  how can I change the default notification which is dislayed on screen when device is locked?

Comment: if you click the notification then only you will receive the details in didReceiveNotification methods @user1324887

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P right now I see something like this in the notification center ` MyAppName , Alert Data`. I need to change this default message, how can I change that?

Comment: message coming from server. its only handled in server side. if you will create a local notification can you customize that./ but not possible to customize the server side push notification in your end. it only possible in server side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118189/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-user1324887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 First uninstall the app and try it. It will work fine same problem i am facing.

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = APPLICATION_ID;
        configuration.clientKey = CLIENT_KEY;
        configuration.server = AMAZON_SERVER;
    }]];

    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    [Fabric with:@[[Digits class]]];



    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]!=TRUE)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    //storedevice Type in standardUserDefaults
    [self setDeviceType];
       #here i am edited

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
   {


    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

}
else
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];


}



    return YES;
}
// remove the below methods

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary * apsData = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSString* alert = [apsData objectForKey:@"alert"];
    ...
    ...

        UIAlertView* alertWindow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: alertHeader
                                                    message: message
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertWindow show];
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    } else {
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement says that if your `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` instance has implemented `registerUserNotificationSettings:` method, then it will execute if block, otherwise it will execute else block.