# APNS: Receive silent Remote Notification if app was force quit

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am looking desperately for a way to receive silent remote notifications when the user has force quit his app.

I already experimented with this a while ago.
The only way to do that, was to remove the `content-available` flag. But then it wasn't a silent notification anymore. The main use case was to download additional content to the remote notification and only then schedule a local notification in turn.

As the new `UNNotification` Framework was introduced they also introduced the new `Notification Service Extension` which provides an elegant way to download content corresponding to a remote notification.

But there is still no way to do the same with silent notifications when the app is force closed. Or did I miss something ?

PS: Maybe it is a duplicate, but other threads do not respect the `Notification Service Extension`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in localisation also discussed here: 
[Change language of alert in banner of Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609923/change-language-of-alert-in-banner-of-push-notification)

I also use the new Notification Service Extension in combination to alter content before the notification is delivered.

Answer (score 1):

When app force closed. AppDelegate method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
}
```

will not called. But if your json payload contain `aps` you will see instant message, after you swipe (or click on notification) method will be called.

You can look `google` and find table of difference silent and normal state and their work in other `Application State`

Comment: This is quite dissatisfying since I have to tackle Localisation.

Comment: This seems to be quite suitable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609923/change-language-of-alert-in-banner-of-push-notification. I will try this tomorrow. Handling localisation on the server is not an option!

Comment: u can localise aps title . `loc-title` or something like this. i dont remember )