# Parse Server (2.6.3) - Localized Push Notifications

Tags: push-notification, localization, parse-server

I have some `afterSave` triggers on my cloud code, where push notifications are being sent from. Recently, we localised our iOS app and we want to do the same on push notifications.

I couldn't find any documentation from Parse about it! Any idea on how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism (neither in Parse nor in Push in general), so you'd have to handle this yourself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18610164/5471218) for a rundown of server-side or client-side localization:

- If you know all possible texts up-front, you can put them in  `Localizable.strings` files, send the localization key via push, and look up the strings it in the app.
- If you need more flexibility (e.g. texts change often or are generated based on other values) you have to perform the localization on the server: you need to know the preferred language of each user (an easy way for that is to save the language code in a property on the current `User` object in the app), then on the server group your users by language and send each group the appropriate notification text.