# Flutter - How to format title and body of notification in background?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to display localized notification in flutter using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging), I am getting a json with 3 language strings in body of a notification like so:

```
{"it": "italian text", "de": "german text", "en": "english text"}
```

As of now, it is showing the whole json string in the notification tray. How can I select the appropriate language text from the json and show in notification when app is in background? myBackgroundMessageHandler this function is never called. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get myBackgroundMessageHandler function to call when in background. I did find a couple of ways to localize notifications using loc_key like tags in iOS like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18610164/6393618) and in android like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification).

However, this method was not suitable for my case because I had to send a bulk text (for example for sending promotions) in the notification. So I ended up saving the device's language in the backend when user subscribes something. That way backend can send the notification only in that language to that device.